# Unable to open react application from another broswer

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, cross-browser

I am new to learning react.
I made a react app with name `projectone`
Then i went to cmd and typed `cd projectone`
and then `npm start`

[I got this displayed on my screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zHYM0.png)

It automatically opened https://localhost:3000 in Edge broswer.
I don't really use Edge so I tried opening it with chrome. but it shows `This site can’t provide a secure connection localhost sent an invalid response.`

How do i fix this?

Comment: Try making your favourite browser as default one.

Comment: Where and how do I do that? Do I do this from cmd?

Comment: Refer [this](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95417?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en#zippy=%2Cwindows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can type "https" by accident inside chrome search bar.

Change it from this:

```
https://localhost:3000
```

.. to this:

```
http://localhost:3000
```

Comment: Thank you! It's opening in all browsers now :)